# Size of class in bytes

Tags: ruby, class, memory, methods

Is there a method to see the size of allocated memory for a class in ruby?

I have built a custom class and I would like to know its size in memory. So is there a function with the likeness of `sizeof()` in C?

I am simply trying to initialize a new class like so

```
test = MyClass.new
```

and trying to find a method to print out the size of the class that has been allocated to memory.

Is this even possible in ruby?

Comment: There are at least two complications to this question: 1) All properties of an object are also objects of other classes, so you need to be clear on whether those are included. 2) The number and types of instance variables are dynamic in Ruby, so there is not really such a thing as the memory size of a class. However, you could in theory measure the memory currently allocated to an object (although I don't currently know how, or if Ruby lets you do this).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no language feature that calculates the size of a class in the same way as C.

The memory size of an object is implementation dependent. It depends on the implementation of the base class object. It is also not simple to estimate the memory used. For example, strings can be embedded in an RString structure if they are short, but stored in the heap if they are long ([Never create Ruby strings longer than 23 characters](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/4/never-create-ruby-strings-longer-than-23-characters)).

The memory taken by some objects has been tabulated for different ruby implementations: [Memory footprint of objects in Ruby 1.8, EE, 1.9, and OCaml](http://eigenclass.org/R2/writings/object-size-ruby-ocaml)

Finally, the object size may differ even with two objects from the same class, since it is possible to arbitrarily add extra instance variables, without hardcoding what instance variables are present. For example, see [instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) and [instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set)

---

If you use MRI ruby 1.9.2+, there is a method you can try (be warned that it is looking at only part of the object, this is obvious from the fact that integers and strings appear to have zero size):

```
irb(main):176:0> require 'objspace'
=> true
irb(main):176:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of(134)
=> 0
irb(main):177:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of("asdf")
=> 0
irb(main):178:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of({a: 4})
=> 184
irb(main):179:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of({a: 4, b: 5})
=> 232
irb(main):180:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of(/a/.match("a"))
=> 80
```

You can also try memsize_of_all (note that it looks at the memory usage of the whole interpreter, and overwriting a variable does not appear to delete the old copy immediately):

```
irb(main):190:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all
=> 4190347
irb(main):191:0> asdf = 4
=> 4
irb(main):192:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all
=> 4201350
irb(main):193:0> asdf = 4
=> 4
irb(main):194:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all
=> 4212353
irb(main):195:0> asdf = 4.5
=> 4.5
irb(main):196:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all
=> 4223596
irb(main):197:0> asdf = "a"
=> "a"
irb(main):198:0> ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all
=> 4234879
```

You should be very careful because there is no guarantee when the Ruby interpreter will perform garbage collection. While you might use this for testing and experimentation, it is recommended that this is NOT used in production!

Comment: How about this then. is it possible to initialize X number of classes and then pull the memory usage of the ruby interpreter before and after? I'm running into a problem where each socket in their own thread will get a single copy of 3 of my classes (for packet handling and such) so if there are 10 connections that is 30 instances of each of my classes. I was wondering if this would be a fundamental design problem and I would have to recode/think my packet handling, or if 3 classes results in miniscule memory usage.

Comment: this is yielding interesting results, when i simply run `puts ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all` i get a value estimated at `1180174` but when i run `(0..1000).each do |i|; t.push PacketParser.new i; end` and `puts ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all` i get `920578` which is less than what it was without initializing over 3000 of my classes. is there something that i am missing here, besides garbage handling? is it not actually creating 3000 classes but simply referencing the 3 classes or something?

Comment: it's quite impossible for me to answer - you could check every iteration (maybe you'll see sudden decreases in some iterations). You should be aware that you are not only allocating memory for your objects in the iteration above. The PacketParser constructor, and the t.push method may also allocate local variables which (temporarily) increase memory usage.

Comment: well i've ran some theoretical tests and i have come to a satisfactory conclusion which i can live with. thanks for all the help